# How is contract code distributed

Tags: corda

Is the contract handling code essentially just Java and run by the server ?.
If I want to edit a contract's functionality do I have to release code to be installed across the network ?.

Answer (score 2):

Great question.  The Corda technical whitepaper talks about this.  See e.g. section 5.9: https://docs.corda.net/_static/corda-technical-whitepaper.pdf

The short answer is that some of this infrastructure still needs to be built out but the key idea is that a State doesn't just say "the Java class with this name governs my evolution"; it says: "the Java class with this name, living in a JAR with this hash governs my evolution".  So there will be no room for games caused by people trying to substitute malicious/compromised implementations.

As for how the code gets distributed:  today, it is installed in each node locally.  Very soon, it will be able to migrate around the network using the Attachments functionality.

And I should add: the contract verification logic will run in a very strict sandbox: both to limit what it can do and to ensure it is 100% deterministic... we can't have one node thinking a transaction is valid and another one thinking it is invalid!

Comment: changing an existing contract's functionality mid flight is obviously highly problematic. transparency, knowing what a contract actually does, is another issue. this is obviously exacerbated if the code isnt encapsulated.

Comment: i meant encapsulated environment. my instinct regarding network validated application code is that this is an accident waiting for a programmer to inadvertently trigger.

Comment: All Corda contract code will run inside a sandboxed environment -
 essentially a lightweight, deterministic JVM. Please see section 13 of the technical white paper (https://docs.corda.net/_static/corda-technical-whitepaper.pdf) for further detail. Cheers

Comment: Hi Mark - yes.. just to be completely clear:  once a transaction is finalised (ie signed and notarised), the ONLY contract code that will be authoritative as to the validity of that transaction is the code specified (by class name and hash-of-JAR file) by the states within that transaction.  So if you don't know what the code does, you should find out before agreeing to be bound by the transaction, of course. But once signed, the implementation won't be able to be changed without your OK.

Answer (score 1):

As Richard notes, states reference contracts. Indeed, there is a `contract` property in the base `ContractState` interface:

```
@CordaSerializable
interface ContractState {
    val contract: Contract
    val participants: List<AbstractParty>
}
```

A Corda transaction is required to change any state property. Therefore, if one party wishes to novate/update the contract code then they must propose a transaction which changes the contract reference then ask all required `participants` to assent to this change.

Comment: i am more concerned with accidental problems, just what programmers do when they have enough rope, than a malicious attack, though they have to be defended of course. perhaps "whats the plan with encapsulated environment" should be my next question.